# How to use different "Commit email" for different repos in the same Gitlab profile?

Tags: gitlab

When logged to Gitlab, in the [profile settings](https://gitlab.com/-/profile) you can set the so-called **Commit email**:

[image: Gitlab "Commit email"]

This is a profile-wide setting.

Given I have more than one email address associated with my profile:

- me@private.com
- me@work.io

I'd like to define a different **Commit email** per repository (or ideally per group).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible right now. But there is already a feature request for this:  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26710